# EIP712 implementation for web3 1.0

Tags: web3js, signature, eip

I tried replicating the instructions in this article to implement EIP712 signing, however, it doesn't appear to work for web3 1.0 versions.

https://medium.com/metamask/eip712-is-coming-what-to-expect-and-how-to-use-it-bb92fd1a7a26

Here's the working signing example from the above article:

https://weijiekoh.github.io/eip712-signing-demo/index.html

And here's the code from the example that works on earlier web3 versions:

```
const domain = [
  { name: "name", type: "string" },
  { name: "version", type: "string" },
  { name: "chainId", type: "uint256" },
  { name: "verifyingContract", type: "address" },
  { name: "salt", type: "bytes32" },
];

const bid = [
  { name: "amount", type: "uint256" },
  { name: "bidder", type: "Identity" },
];

const identity = [
  { name: "userId", type: "uint256" },
  { name: "wallet", type: "address" },
];

const chainId = parseInt(web3.version.network, 10);

const domainData = {
  name: "My amazing dApp",
  version: "2",
  chainId: chainId,
  verifyingContract: "0x1C56346CD2A2Bf3202F771f50d3D14a367B48070",
  salt: "0xf2d857f4a3edcb9b78b4d503bfe733db1e3f6cdc2b7971ee739626c97e86a558"
};

var message = {
  amount: 100,
  bidder: {
    userId: 323,
    wallet: "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333"
  }
};

const data = JSON.stringify({
  types: {
    EIP712Domain: domain,
    Bid: bid,
    Identity: identity,
  },
  domain: domainData,
  primaryType: "Bid",
  message: message
});

const signer = web3.toChecksumAddress(web3.eth.accounts[0]);

web3.currentProvider.sendAsync(
  {
    method: "eth_signTypedData_v3",
    params: [signer, data],
    from: signer
  }, 
  function(err, result) {
    if (err || result.error) {
      return console.error(result);
    }

    const signature = parseSignature(result.result.substring(2));

    res.style.display = "block";
    res.value = genSolidityVerifier(signature, signer, chainId);
  }
);
```

This works with maybe a few minor modifications, except for the last section, which I'm not sure how to update. If I simply update the `sendAsync` section to the below, I get a stringified version of the data to sign to show up in MetaMask, however, it's not very readable and the better solution would be to get the proper object format like the example.

```
web3.eth.personal.sign(data, props.address ,'');
```

Any ideas are appreciated.